# How to represent alternates in a Go xml struct tag

Tags: go, xml-parsing

I'm trying to write the appropriate set of struct tags to parse the [XML version of UCUM](http://unitsofmeasure.org/ucum-essence.xml). Following are two examples of the `unit` tag:

```
<unit Code="deg" CODE="DEG" isMetric="no" class="iso1000">
   <name>degree</name>
   <printSymbol>&#176;</printSymbol>
   <property>plane angle</property>
   <value Unit="[pi].rad/360" UNIT="[PI].RAD/360" value="2">2</value>
</unit>

<unit Code="[degF]" CODE="[DEGF]" isMetric="no" isSpecial="yes" class="heat">
   <name>degree Fahrenheit</name>
   <printSymbol>&#176;F</printSymbol>
   <property>temperature</property>
   <value Unit="degf(5 K/9)" UNIT="DEGF(5 K/9)">
      <function name="degF" value="5" Unit="K/9"/>
   </value>
</unit>
```

The tricky part is the contents of the `value` tag, which can either be a string (which I'd represent with a string attribute) or a function (which would require a struct of its own). Here's what I've got so far:

```
type Unit struct {
    Code             string `xml:Code,attr`
    CodeCaps         string `xml:CODE,attr`
    IsMetric         bool   `xml:isMetric,attr,omitempty`
    IsSpecial        bool   `xml:isEmptySpecial,attr,omitempty`
    Class            string `xml:class,attr`
    Name             string `xml:name`
    PrintSymbol      string `xml:printSymbol,chardata`
    DimensionTypeKey string `xml:property,chardata`
    Value            struct {
        Unit       string `xml:Unit,attr`
        UnitCaps   string `xml:UNIT,attr`
        Value      string `xml:Value,attr`
        PrintValue string `xml:,chardata`
        Function   struct { ... }
    } `xml:value`
}
```

How do I accurately describe this XML with struct tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost working; [here's the fixed version](http://play.golang.org/p/rj3FtOJSw_).

Basically you need the following adjustments:

- In struct tags, the values—bits after the `xml:` prefix—must be enclosed in double quotes, like this:

  ```
  `xml:"foo,attr"`
  ```
- There's no need to specify the `,chardata` bit when you already just want to get whatever is between the element's tags.
- To extract the `<function>` element just provide a data type for is: the parser will extract it if it's present or not if it's absent.

  To tell whether there was `<function>` or not, you can check the value of the `PrintValue` field: if it's not all-whitespace, there was no `<function>` element; otherwise there was.

  Alternatively, define a separate `struct` data type for unmarshaling this element, and have the field for it defined as a pointer to that type,
  like in

  ```
  type Function struct { ... }
  ...
  Function *Function `xml:"function"`
  ```

  This way, if there was no `<function>` element the field's value will be `nil`, otherwise it will point to a heap-allocated `Function` instance.